# VMware - High CPU utilization on Windows 7 guest VM

Tags: windows-7, vmware-esxi, cpu-usage

I've just added some Windows 7 virtual machines to an existing VMWare vSphere 5.1 cluster. The hosts and vCenter are 5.1 with current updates via Update Manager.

Looking at the vSphere client performance graphs, I see random sustained jumps in the guest CPU utilization. These are new VM's with no software installed. They were trimmed-down and optimized [according to this guide](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1696256). The VMWare guest tools *are* installed.

The systems are idle as this is happening. There's no corresponding activity within the guest's [Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhmBQ.png) or [Performance chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTYtd.png).

[image]

Any thoughts on what the issue could be? I suspect a guest tools/version interaction, but a root cause would be helpful.

Comment: Have you caught anything in task manager within the VMs when it's happening?

Comment: Yeah, the task manager is flat, even while the vCenter chart shows 100% utilization.

Comment: Is anyone logged in while this is happening?  [I've noticed this bug causing some similar funkiness on my vSphere5.1 VMs.](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2036350)  Turning off logging for VMTools did correct it for me, though I'm not exactly thrilled with that "fix."

Comment: Nobody logged-in. These are freshly-created VMs.

Comment: Hi mate, if you check the host directly, is this spike showing to the same degree?

Comment: Also, do you have vsheild, or any backup appliances running at around this time? Can you run esxtop to see what process is causing the spike? Cause of the timeing and all it does look a bit like an av scan or update or something

Comment: Nothing installed, no backup agents... Seems random. I'll check for Microsoft Security Essentials.

Answer (score 1):

Use [esxtop](http://www.yellow-bricks.com/esxtop/) to check for another world (log into ssh on host and run esxtop). See if you can isolate what is using the resources. If you are running an appliance such as vShield (or there are other situations) you may have a second world created which would be running up the resource usage.

Is [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) reporting any high usage tasks on the host?